# Cannot boot server after power failure

Tags: boot, electrical-power, ipmi, supermicro, power-supply-unit

After a power failure, my server cant boot anymore.

1. Switching power on do nothing. No fans, no boot, no sound. Nothing.
2. Shorting the power switch on the motherboard also do nothing.
3. My motherboard is a Supermicro MB and have IPMI on it. I can access IPMI through the network. (does this rule out PSU failure?)
4. Switching on from IPMI does nothing, unfortunately.
5. Tried turn off the Seasonic PSU and turn it back on does nothing.
6. Tried turn off the Seasonic PSU for hours and turn it back on does nothing.

Any hints? What can I do next to troubleshoot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After rapidly switch on off the psu in furious rage, the server finally boots.

Comment: I'll note for future readers that furious rage might work occasionally, but it does not work _consistently_ and should not be relied on. Better to replace the offending hardware.

Comment: Upvoted -- it turns out that my rage was insufficiently furious.

Comment: I have replaced the PSU with another PSU and still having the same problem. Then I switch the backplane of my server and it works fine since then. Im not sure whether my faulty backplane causing issue to PSU or my faulty psu causing problem to my backplane. My server running flawlessly for few years now. I keep the faulty PSU as spare PSU and recently use it to power my kids pc. After a week of flawless usage, the power issue with the PSU returns again. Now my kids have graduated from learning on how to switch on off the PSU in furious rage and able to use the pc happily.